# Why is "Candy" the answer to "Last two of juicy sweets"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The clue was "Last two of juicy sweets?" and the answer was 'Candy'. I don't understand why.

Comment: Where is this clue from?

Answer (score 17):

Reasoning

> The last two letters of "juicy" are **C AND Y**
>  "sweets" is the definition